# Changing JScrollPane Scrollbar color

Tags: java, swing

I was wondering what I should look into if I would like to change the scrollbar color.
I want the background of the scrollbar and the color to be something else except the default windows colors.

I have searched everywhere as to where I might find the answer, but unfortunately I did not manage to find anything. Any help will be greatly appreciated I really am struggling with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/). You might be able to change some of the defaults. This would affect all scrollbars in your application. Also, the UIManager values are LAF dependent.

Comment: I forgot about this handy app of yours; I've used it myself in the past. Depending on the LAF in use, though, certain properties can be ignored/obstructed, right?

Comment: Yes, there is no guarantee this will work. The only real solution is to create a custom UI for every LAF you want to support.

Answer (score 2):

you will have to look into [ScrollBarUI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/ScrollBarUI.html) class, specially inside of following functions:

```
    protected void paintTrack(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle trackBounds) {
             /// code
    } 
    protected void paintThumb(final Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle thumbBounds) {
      //code
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the basic answer you're looking for is in the [ScrollBarUI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/ScrollBarUI.html) class, but be warned; that way lies madness. Fiddling with UIResources isn't exactly fun - you might just want to Google around for a whole new LnF library that looks more to your liking.

Comment: unfortunately I am not allowed to change anything in lnf :( only scrollbar color must be changed. Your answer is exactly what I feared, however I will trying seeing if I can do it and will accept it shortly.